# Ktor - How to decode base64 token using pure Kotlin in a Kotlin-Multiplatform common module?

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform

It might seem simple at first, but considering that we cannot use the `java.util` package in the `common` module of a Kotlin Multiplatform project, I am wondering how to decode a base64 string using pure Kotlin code.

Already tried:

- using **expect/actual** methods: works fine for Android, but did not work for iOS! It seems like the Swift methods and classes that are for Base64 decoding cannot be used in the kmm module!
- using Ktor's Base64 decoding methods: The Ktor Base64 decoder seems to be an **internal Ktor API** which I could not use in my KMM project.
  I also mentioned that it is marked as **deprecated** for version `1.4.1` in the [ktor docs](https://api.ktor.io/1.4.1/io.ktor.util/decode-base64.html).

I was wondering if there are any other workarounds to decode a Base64 string in a kmm common module.

Comment: This one is not deprecated: https://api.ktor.io/1.4.1/io.ktor.util/decode-base64-bytes.html
Will it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can use [`decodeBase64Bytes()`](https://api.ktor.io/1.4.1/io.ktor.util/decode-base64-bytes.html), which is not deprecated in Ktor 1.4.2